# DatePicker return null in Android

Tags: php, android, sql-server-2008, datepicker

I have a program to SELECT data from database using PHP and DatePicker in Android. My code PHP working when I try run in my browser but when I wanna try run in my android my program just showing Loading like this http://prntscr.com/bo96a8 . I don't know how to fix it my code

My code Android like this

```
Toolbar toolbar;
// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
private EditText toDateEtxt;
private Button click;

private DatePickerDialog fromDatePickerDialog;
private DatePickerDialog toDatePickerDialog;

private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;
private ListView listView;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products = "http://192.168.1.113/history_ip.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "product";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "Name";
private static final String TAG_IP = "IPv4";
private static final String TAG_LOGIN = "Login Date";
private static final String TAG_LOGOUT = "Logout Date";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;
//search key value
public String searchkey;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.history_ip);
    // ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    // Hashmap for ListView
    Intent myIntent = getIntent();
    // gets the arguments from previously created intent
    searchkey = myIntent.getStringExtra("key1");
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    //ListView lv = getListView();
    // Loading products in Background Thread
    //new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    //listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
    TypedValue typedValueColorPrimaryDark = new TypedValue();
    HistoryIP.this.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorPrimary, typedValueColorPrimaryDark, true);
    final int colorPrimaryDark = typedValueColorPrimaryDark.data;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(colorPrimaryDark);
    }
    dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd", Locale.US);
    findViewsById();

    setDateTimeField();
    click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnbanned);
    click.setOnClickListener(this);
}
private void findViewsById() {
    toDateEtxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date);
    toDateEtxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
}

private void setDateTimeField() {
    toDateEtxt.setOnClickListener(this);
    Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    toDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            toDateEtxt.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
            new LoadAllProducts().execute(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()), searchkey);
        }
    },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}

// Get listview
protected ListView getListView(){
    if (listView == null) {
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.historyip);
    }
    return listView;
}

class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(HistoryIP.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String date = args[0];
        String id = args[1];
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", date));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);
        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String ip = c.getString(TAG_IP);
                    String login = c.getString(TAG_LOGIN);
                    String logout = c.getString(TAG_LOGOUT);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_IP, ip);
                    map.put(TAG_LOGIN, login);
                    map.put(TAG_LOGOUT, logout);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Doesn't have top cpt players now", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        //runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        // public void run() {
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                HistoryIP.this, productsList,
                R.layout.list_historyip, new String[]{
                TAG_NAME, TAG_IP, TAG_LOGIN},
                new int[]{R.id.title, R.id.rating, R.id.genre});
        // updating listview
        getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
        //}
        // });
    }
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view == toDateEtxt) {
        toDatePickerDialog.show();
    } else if (view== click){
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_news, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HistoryIP.class);
        startActivity(i);
        //return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Anyone can help me? Thanks before

Answer (score 0):

It is date format issue the date you are passing is in incorrect format 
Please check your webservice date format.It is batter to pass with time zone or use System.currentTimeMillis() http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()

```
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter =
        new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss z", Locale.US);
```

Comment: my format is right sir because I try in browser my code php working without error

Comment: My table database is tbl_UserLogout_Log20160323 and in my php like this tbl_UserLogout_Log$date and I try in browser like this http://prntscr.com/bo9gmo you see working without error

Comment: Whats the output of  Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

Answer (score 0):

u missed to call show. check my edit.

```
  toDateEtxt.setOnClickListener(this);
Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
toDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        toDateEtxt.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
        new LoadAllProducts().execute(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()), searchkey);
    }
},newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
```

Comment: My table database is tbl_UserLogout_Log20160323 and in my php like this tbl_UserLogout_Log$date and I try in browser like this http://prntscr.com/bo9gmo you see working without error

Comment: still same sir I already try like you suggest and still stuck in loading

Comment: wt is my understading is any happens in "doinbackground()" method u should come out with or wihout expection and loading view should go off. i m thinking as ur postExexcute() is not called..  JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params); is this call from any library ? please check is blocking in any ways

Comment: not blocking sir because other feature I use code same and work just datepicker not work for me

Comment: I already try you solution before but still same not stuck in loading sir